# sorting .csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort my csv.

My csv without sorting looks like
[image: this].
I am trying to sort my csv file by numbers in **ATOM_id** in ascending order. This is my code snippet `df.sort_values(["ATOMS_ID"],axis = 0, ascending = [True],inplace = True)`. This is what I
[image: get].
I am not really sure why my .csv is not get sorted as 1,2,3,... but it is getting 1,10,100... .

Also, I was wondering about how to undo the sorting?

Thanks!!

Comment: It is likely that your ATOM_ID is a string and not numeric.

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't think about it. Thanks! I will try converting it to int.

Comment: As to how to undo the sorting, you don't. Generally it's a good practice to either omit `inplace=True` and just view the result, or assign the output to a different object like `df2=df.sort_values(["ATOMS_ID"],axis = 0, ascending = [True])` unless you're sure the output is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting column might be in string type, not integer. You could check it with:

```
df.dtypes
```

It will show you what data type each column has.

Then for convert:

```
df["ATOMS_ID"] = df["ATOMS_ID"].astype(int)
```

Then try sorting again see if it works.